# Keep getting Uncaught Syntax error in my Express server.js with Angular 1.5.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Been trying for a couple hours to get Angular with use Routs I've created. Finally decided to try using Express and so I set up a simple server.js file to run as a stand along server.

But nothing works and I keep getting the same error

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

All my files are in the public dir of my app like so

```
server.js
 /public
  main.html
   /lib
      angular/
      bootstrap/ 
   /views/
      search.html
      list.html
   /scripts
      app.js
      controllers.js
```

My server.js file is pretty simple

```
 var express = require('express'),
 app = express();

 app.use(express.static('/public'))
 .get('*',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('./public/main.html');
 })
 .listen(3000);
```

Here's my app.js / routes

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ui-leaflet'])
.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/search',{
            controller: 'searchCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/search.html'
        })
        .when('/list',{
            controller: 'listCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/list.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/search'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Finally here is my main.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <base href="/">
 <html ng-app="myApp" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>MY APP</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there being thrown on the back-end or on the front-end?  Also, usually that error is usually accompanied with a line/column number pointing out where the issue is.  It's most likely a basic syntax error.

Comment: Not that I can see. I thought it was a typo at first as well, but I'm pretty certin is the server.js file that's causing the issue. But I'm new to express

Comment: when you run server.js is the error showing up in the terminal?  Or is the error in the developer console in the browser?

Comment: the error is showing up in the browser console window

Answer (score 0):

Try serving your html file like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

//middleware to resolve root directory
app.use("/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname)));

//this is assuming index.html and server.js are in the same directory
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Okay, is require path a different npm package?

Comment: Nope. does not work either. Even with server.js and index.html in the same dir.

Comment: Okay. I think I'm getting some where. My main index page now loads and its including my libraries but does not route?  No errors.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it doesn't route".  The above code doesn't show your other views html files or mention how you are switching between views.  It's good the app it being served, but I would suggest reading up on angular routing to solve any remaining issues. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09